# Hyperref and articles with parts (KOMA script issue?)

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, koma-script

This has probably been asked before, but how can I make `hyperref` play nicely on articles (using the KOMA `scrartcl` class) that have Parts but no Chapters? It complains with:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 90.
```

The bookmarks get messed up, with the next section becoming "promoted" to one level up. Interestingly enough, this doesn't occur using the stock `article` class.

```
% vim: ft=tex tw=0

% arara: lualatex: { synctex: true, shell: true }
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: true, shell: true }

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\title{A minimum working example}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Robbie Smith},
  pdftitle={A minimum working example},
  pdfcreator={An infinite number of gremlins hitting random keys on typewriters...},
  pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
  colorlinks=false,
  hypertexnames=false,
  hidelinks}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\part{Design and Testing}

\section{Objective}

\blindtext

\section{Summary}
\label{sec:summary}

\blindtext

\section{Geometric design}
\label{sec:geometry}

\blindtext

\subsection{Final geometic design}
\label{ssec:geo:final}

The final geometric design is provided in the table below. Formulae references
are to the calculations in the above sections.

\blindtext

\section{Fabrication}
\label{sec:fabrication}

\blindtext

\section{Testing}
\label{sec:testing}

\blindtext

\section{Proposed improvements}
\label{sec:improvements}

\blindtext

\section{Conclusions}
\label{sec:conclusions}

\blindtext

\appendix
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}

\part{Preliminary Designs}
\label{part:preliminary-designs}

The preliminary designs were developed prior to building and testing.

\section{First Iteration}

\blindtext

\subsection{Something something}

\blindtext

\section{Second Iteration}

\blindtext

\section{Third Iteration}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The log for compiling with `lualatex` via `latexmk` is included below:

```
$ latexmk mwe.tex
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Jan. 2018, version: 4.55.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex --synctex=1 --shell-escape  -recorder  "mwe.tex"'
------------
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)
 system commands enabled.
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 3
(using write cache: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(using rea
d cache: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic /home/faraday/.config
/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.104 seconds
Babel <3.20> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo(load luc: /
opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc
)) (/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer-scrpage.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/hypcap.sty) (./mwe.aux)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))(load lu
c: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmsans10-regular.
luc)(load luc: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmsan
s10-bold.luc)(load luc: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/
otl/lmroman12-regular.luc)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

(load luc: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmromansl
ant10-regular.luc) [1{/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdfte
x.map}]
part I.

Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 33.

[2] [3]
part II.

Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 86.


Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 90.

[4] [5] (./mwe.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `mwe.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

)
 380 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 attribute, 50 glue_spec, 3 attribute_lis
t, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:260,3:85,4:5,5:181,6:37,7:3890,8:37,9:154,10:4,11:314
</opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf></
opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-regular.otf></op
t/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-bold.otf>
Output written on mwe.pdf (5 pages, 21070 bytes).
SyncTeX written on mwe.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on mwe.log.
=== TeX engine is 'LuaTeX'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'mwe.pdf'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'mwe.aux'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex --synctex=1 --shell-escape  -recorder  "mwe.tex"'
------------
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)
 system commands enabled.
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 3
(using write cache: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(using rea
d cache: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic /home/faraday/.config
/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.103 seconds
Babel <3.20> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo(load luc: /
opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc
)) (/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer-scrpage.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/hypcap.sty) (./mwe.aux)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./mwe.out) (./mwe.out)(load luc: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gene
ric/fonts/otl/lmsans10-regular.luc)(load luc: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luate
x-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmsans10-bold.luc)(load luc: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman12-regular.luc)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

(./mwe.toc)(load luc: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/ot
l/lmromanslant10-regular.luc) [1{/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/u
pdmap/pdftex.map}]
part I.

Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 33.

[2] [3]
part II.

Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 86.


Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 90.

[4] [5] (./mwe.aux))
 400 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 attribute, 54 glue_spec, 3 attribute_lis
t, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:563,3:140,4:5,5:181,6:58,7:3894,8:49,9:203,10:4,11:314
</opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf></
opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-regular.otf></op
t/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-bold.otf>
Output written on mwe.pdf (5 pages, 23032 bytes).
SyncTeX written on mwe.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on mwe.log.
=== TeX engine is 'LuaTeX'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'mwe.pdf'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'mwe.aux'
      'mwe.out'
      'mwe.toc'
------------
Run number 3 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex --synctex=1 --shell-escape  -recorder  "mwe.tex"'
------------
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)
 system commands enabled.
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 3
(using write cache: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(using rea
d cache: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic /home/faraday/.config
/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.096 seconds
Babel <3.20> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo(load luc: /
opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc
)) (/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer-scrpage.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/hypcap.sty) (./mwe.aux)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./mwe.out) (./mwe.out)(load luc: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gene
ric/fonts/otl/lmsans10-regular.luc)(load luc: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luate
x-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmsans10-bold.luc)(load luc: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman12-regular.luc)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

(./mwe.toc)(load luc: /opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/ot
l/lmromanslant10-regular.luc) [1{/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/u
pdmap/pdftex.map}]
part I.

Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 33.

[2] [3]
part II.

Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 86.


Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 90.

[4] [5] (./mwe.aux))
 400 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 attribute, 54 glue_spec, 3 attribute_lis
t, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:563,3:140,4:5,5:181,6:58,7:3894,8:49,9:203,10:4,11:314
</opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf></
opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-regular.otf></op
t/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-bold.otf>
Output written on mwe.pdf (5 pages, 23032 bytes).
SyncTeX written on mwe.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on mwe.log.
=== TeX engine is 'LuaTeX'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'mwe.pdf'
Latexmk: All targets (mwe.pdf) are up-to-date
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warnings are related to KOMA-Script. The "MWE" works fine with KOMA-Script 2015/10/03 v3.19a (`scrartcl.cls`).

The latest version 2018/03/30 v3.25 redefines `\toclevel@part` from 0 to −1, leaving a gap of 2 between the levels "part" and "section".

The first two warnings are caused by this gap from "part" to "section". Package `hyperref` fixes this by giving the section after part the level 0. The the following `\subsection` with level 2 throws the third warning.

Fix:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\toclevel@part}{0}
\makeatother
```

Recommended is package `bookmark`. It also fixes the issue, because its improved algorithm supports level gaps (and the fix above is not needed).
Also, it updates the bookmarks faster (often a second run is not needed).

Comment: Sorry, the warning line number was from my original document which I stripped down to make the MWE. It's actually line 90, so I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: That's really odd. I've attached the log from mine to the question, and I get three warnings from `hyperref`, on line 33, 86, and 90.

Comment: Loading the `bookmark` package fixed it, thank you :)

Comment: @Robbie I can now reproduce the warnings with a newer KOMA-Script (2018/03/30 v3.25). It changes the bookmark level for parts. Therefore, I have rewritten the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This problem does not longer happen with KOMA-Script v3.26 because `scrartcl` now automatically loads `bookmarks` if `hyperref` is loaded. It also has a workaround for the case, that loading of `bookmark` is prevented, so even:

```
% vim: ft=tex tw=0

% arara: lualatex: { synctex: true, shell: true }
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: true, shell: true }

\documentclass[bookmarkpackage=false]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\title{A minimum working example}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Robbie Smith},
  pdftitle={A minimum working example},
  pdfcreator={An infinite number of gremlins hitting random keys on typewriters...},
  pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
  colorlinks=false,
  hypertexnames=false,
  hidelinks}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\part{Design and Testing}

\section{Objective}

\blindtext

\section{Summary}
\label{sec:summary}

\blindtext

\section{Geometric design}
\label{sec:geometry}

\blindtext

\subsection{Final geometic design}
\label{ssec:geo:final}

The final geometric design is provided in the table below. Formulae references
are to the calculations in the above sections.

\blindtext

\section{Fabrication}
\label{sec:fabrication}

\blindtext

\section{Testing}
\label{sec:testing}

\blindtext

\section{Proposed improvements}
\label{sec:improvements}

\blindtext

\section{Conclusions}
\label{sec:conclusions}

\blindtext

\appendix
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}

\part{Preliminary Designs}
\label{part:preliminary-designs}

The preliminary designs were developed prior to building and testing.

\section{First Iteration}

\blindtext

\subsection{Something something}

\blindtext

\section{Second Iteration}

\blindtext

\section{Third Iteration}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

does result in correct bookmarks:

[image: The bookmarks]

and without a `hyperref` warning. But in this case `scrartcl` itself warns:

> ```
> Class scrartcl Warning: Trying emergency fix for bookmark level gap,
> (scrartcl)              because toclevel of `part' (-1)
> (scrartcl)              is more than 1 lower than currently lowest
> (scrartcl)              known level (1).
> (scrartcl)              Note: This fix can fail and you should load
> (scrartcl)              package `bookmark' to avoid usage of this
> (scrartcl)              fix on input line 24.
> ```

After removing option `bookmarkpackage=false` the warning disappears. But now, `auxhook` writes an information to the `log`-file:

> ```
> Package auxhook Info: \AddLineBeginMainAux comes a little late,
> (auxhook)             because the main .aux file is already opened on input lin
> e 164.
> ```

So the recommended solution is still to add a `\usepackage{bookmark}` after loading `hyperref`.